# How to get Youtube iframe on pasting url in input text field

Tags: jquery, youtube

My HTML looks something like this[image]

And after pasting youtube or vimeo url in input box i need to get the youtube/vimeo iframe below it, without reloading page. Something like this:[image]

I tried capturing the url on keyup function but i'm unable to get the iframe.
My code is

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="video-url">Paste a Vimeo or YouTube video URL here</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="video" name="video" placeholder="Video URL" type="url">
</div>
<div id="video" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="video-preview"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="video-title">Caption/Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="video-title" maxlength="100" name="video" placeholder="Video Title" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
 var videobox = document.getElementById('video');
 $('#video').on('input', function() {
   var url =$('#video').val()); 
   videobox.style.display = "block";
  });
})
</script>
```

How can i get it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: paste at least your code

Comment: pasted @Roljhon !! Now could you please answer this or you are also the one who are here only to tell us the rules ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, your div and your input field having the same ID is not correct, when referencing in javascript, it will be referenced to the input field, not on the div. That's why `style.display` didn't work or didn't display your div.

> Second, when working with iframes, you should be considering CORS issues which vimeo and youtube doesn't actually provide that much (using their API is really recommended for this kind of scenario most of the time), so consider embedding in general and take note of the video URL that are pasted

**Solution:**

- Replace the id attribute of the div from `video` to `videobox`
- Create Iframe element and append to `video-preview`
- Take note of the URL used, its for embedding not a normal URL used in the browser

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
 var videobox = document.getElementById('videobox');
 $('#video').on('keyup', function() {
   if($(this).val() === "") {
 videobox.style.display = "none";
   }else{
 var url =$(this).val(); 
 var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
 ifrm.src = (!url.includes('vimeo')) ? "//www.youtube.com/embed/"+ url.split("=")[1] : "//player.vimeo.com/video/"+ url.split("/")[3];
 ifrm.width= "560";
 ifrm.height = "560";
 ifrm.frameborder="0";
 ifrm.scrolling="no";
 $('#video-preview').html(ifrm);
 videobox.style.display = "block";
   }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="video-url">Paste a Vimeo or YouTube video URL here</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="video" name="video" placeholder="Video URL" type="url">
</div>
<div id="videobox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="video-preview"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="video-title">Caption/Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="video-title" maxlength="100" name="video" placeholder="Video Title" type="text">
    </div>
```

**Note:** *If you want to get the video information like title/caption, you should be using their API*

Comment: Works Perfectly !!

Answer (score -1):

Method 1:
Use **onchange** event, passing **$this** in the function, then get **$this** value and change the iframe src with the new value of **$this**.

Method 2 (with some mods on your code):

```
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="video-url">Paste a Vimeo or YouTube video URL here</label>
                 <input class="form-control" id="video" name="video" onchange="displayIt(); return false;" placeholder="Video URL" type="url">
            </div>
            <div id="videocontainer" style="display: none;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div id="video-preview"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="video-title">Caption/Title</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="video-title" maxlength="100" name="video" placeholder="Video Title" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

        <script>


    function displayIt(){
        var url =$('#video').val();
        $('<iframe src="'+ url +'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>').appendTo($('#video-preview'));
        $('#videocontainer').css('display', 'block');
alert('you should put your hand to learn jquery not to wait for full solutions, this is a quite a beginner question, only append iframe to the div with the new value')

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: have you even tried this before posting your answer?

Comment: can you really load your videos using your solution? have tried running on any fiddle?

Comment: You don't really need the code above you need this http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: I'm preparing a fiddle wait for it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oyn6bf5s/2/ input url-> https:// www.youtube.com/embed/pNFY7t8tJLg

Comment: Also you will need to clean the contents of the video-preview when the displayIt function runs with $('#video-preview').html(''), see http://api.jquery.com/html/